# Implied volatility extrapolate to longer maturities

Tags: implied-volatility

So we are looking at some security names with limited amount of listed options. Some of them only have listed options that expire in less than a year. Is there a quick way to extrapolate the vol surface / term structure based on listed options, forward price, and maybe index options with longer maturity? Many thanks!